# Need help parsing jquery datatables editor data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have a data format that I receive from jquery data tables editor [Datatables Editor](http://editor.datatables.net) which looks like the one below and I need to parse it so that I can store it into db but I have not figured out a way of doing so.

```
 { action: 'edit',
     'data[1][Name]': 'Some Text ',
     'data[1][Rating]': '1',
     'data[1][Division]': 'Some Text '
 }
```

What is the best way to parse this form of data using javascript ? The editor library comes with a php library for parsing the data but I am using nodejs for the backend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert `data[]` into a literal, you could do something like this :

```
var prop, fieldName, literal = {};
for (prop in data) {
    if (prop != 'action') {
        fieldName = prop.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g)[1].replace(/\]|\[/g,'');
        literal[fieldName] = data[prop];
    } 
}
```

→[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j05750p0/). It will produce a literal like

```
{Name: "Some Text ", Rating: "1", Division: "Some Text "}
```

that can be used to be inserted in a mongodb for example.

It simply loops through data, extracts each #2 `[]` and take the content of that bracket as property names to the literal. I do not at all claim this is the best method.

Comment: Thanks, I also came to the same conclusion.I ran an each loop in underscopre and used regex to change the names.

Comment: @Bazinga777 - OK, then it cannot be completely foolish :) `'data[1][Division]'` etc is a little bit odd input, there is no real good shorthand for converting it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have new and maybe a bit more systematic approach, that excludes risc of '[]' characters in regexed strings. Very simple way is to use custom ajax, I have used my own data:

```
const editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    ajax: (method, url, data, success, error) => {           
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/updateproductcode',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: (json) => {
                success(json);
            },
            error: (xhr, error, thrown) => {
                error(xhr, error, thrown);
            }
        });
    },
    table: '#mytable',
    idSrc: 'productcode',
    fields: ...
```

Then on serverside you receive object, whose key is your stringified data:

```
{'{"action":"edit","data":{"08588001339265":{"productcode":"08588001339265","name":"does_not_existasdfadsf","pdkname":"Prokain Penicilin G 1.5 Biotika ims.inj.s.10x1.5MU","suklcode":"0201964","pdkcode":"2895002"}
}:''}
```

If you parse the key of it with `JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0])`, you get your results:

```
{ action: 'edit',
  data:
   { '08588001339265':
      { productcode: '08588001339265',
        name: 'does_not_existasdfadsf',
        pdkname: 'Prokain Penicilin G 1.5 Biotika ims.inj.s.10x1.5MU',
        suklcode: '0201964',
        pdkcode: '2895002' } } }
```